# Big Oh Notation Definition?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

Can someone please explain to me what this means:

Definition: Given functions f(n) and g(n), then we say that
          f(n) is O( g(n) )

if and only if there exist positive constants c and n0   such that
        f(n) <= c g(n)      for all n => n0

Comment: It's a simple math statement. Read it carefully as many times as you need until you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means, that for large enough `n` and ignoring constant factors, `f(n)` does not grow faster than `g(n)`.